# Is scales package included in tidyverse?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I use a percentage formatting function from the scales package in this line of code:

```
ggplot(gun_deaths3, aes(x = police2, fill = race)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

I am confused about whether I would need to do

```
library(scales)
```

at the beginning of my code or not if I already loaded tidy verse. I haven't manually installed the scales package and it seems to be running so I'm not sure if I need that extra line of code or not. Thanks!

Comment: You can test this yourself; remove `scales::`, run the code in a clean R session, and if you get a "can't fund function" error, then you'll need `library(scales)`. Otherwise, not.

Comment: yes and no. As @Brandon says, tidyverse doesn't load `scales`. But if you use the `scales::` idiom, you don't need to load the package explicitly with `library()`.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if `scales::` would allow it to run on someone else's computer if they didn't have the scales package loaded. Guess it will

Comment: It would not work on someone else's computer if they did not have the `scales` package installed. Of course it is extremely uncommon for someone not to have `scales`.

Comment: `scales` will generally be installed when `ggplot2` is installed. It's conceivable that it wouldn't be, but in that case they'd get an error in any case. If you think this is likely you could give them information on how to run `install.packages("scales")` if necessary (but  I wouldn't recommend making it part of your script)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no.

https://tidyverse.tidyverse.org/

> `library(tidyverse)` will load the core tidyverse packages:
>
> - `ggplot2`, for data visualisation.
> - `dplyr`, for data manipulation.
> - `tidyr`, for data tidying.
> - `readr`, for data import.
> - `purrr`, for functional programming.
> - `tibble`, for tibbles, a modern re-imagining of data frames.

When you specify a function using the full package notation (ie `package::function()`) you do not need to load the package earlier using `library(package)`, you just need to have the package installed.